# JHipster Authority doesn't allow to add more than two authorities

Tags: jhipster

I'm unable to add more than two authorities in route.ts. As I have five `USER_ROLE` in my `jhi_authority` table.

Comment: Why are you unable?

Comment: we have different route file in which we give authoties to different usertype of like ['ROLE_USER']['ROLE_ADMIN'] . when  i add third ROLE its gives error

Comment: Please edit your question with clarifications. What prevents you from adding more authorities to array?

Comment: What does "its gives error" mean? Is there any error message you want to share with us?

Comment: if i add this code in setting.route.ts file **data: {authorities: ['ROLE_DOCTOR']['ROLE_ADMIN']['ROLE_PATIENT'] }** i got error in cosole like **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ROLE_PATIENT' of undefined**.means last parameter value not condsidering. **i found one solution that blank the **authorities : []**

Comment: temperory i blank the authorities array so that everyone can access that page.
**but in future if i want to give more than two specific user then what should i do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you showed in comments is wrong, `authorities` expects an array of strings like this :

```
{
   authorities: ['ROLE_DOCTOR', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_PATIENT'] 
}
```